# How to call super funciton in js Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i need clarity about `_super` in JS.
I tried to inherit a widget and call a super method. I tried a different way to super the function. Only one way got worked. But when analysing the Odoo source code we can see other methods are used for supering a method. I need to know why Odoo uses different super methods at different times.

Here is my sample code:

***.js**

```
         odoo.define('pos_session_route.payment', function (require) {
      "use strict";

      var account_payment = require('account.payment');
      var AbstractField = require('web.AbstractField');
      var core = require('web.core');
      var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');

      var QWeb = core.qweb;
      var _t = core._t;
        console.log('paymenyyyyy',account_payment);

              account_payment.ShowPaymentLineWidget.include({
      //        AbstractField.include({

                  payment_widget : function () {

                  console.log('paymenyyyyy');

                  },
                  _render:function(){
                  console.log('hihooo');
      // account_payment.prototype._super.apply(this.arguments); didn't work
      // account_payment.ShowPaymentLineWidget.prototype._super.apply(this.arguments); didn't work
      // this._super.apply(this, arguments);didn't work
                  this._super(this.arguments); it works

                  }

                  })


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 15, the `AbstractField` is an Owl Component.

With Owl Components, you better call the super with `super(...arguments);`

For non Owl Components, you can call the super with `this._super.apply(this, arguments);`

Also, reading your code, I'd suggest you separate what you're doing in the `AbstractField` and what you're doing in your `account_payment`. But that's not my business, you can have your reasons to do so ^^

Hope it helped !